# HTML form without CSRF protection alert (Acunetix)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

I use in my form  `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` and in action I use `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute but when test my site by **Acunetix**  get this error :

> HTML form without CSRF protection

html :

```
<form action="/Car/SearchCar?uniq=-107215139" method="POST" name="form" id="FormCarSearch">
    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="NpoBFo4bSCwbm0yZ6dIrpOazM00uX-rKNbru9sfVPGV9cJ8qaDsYaAqsRDDKuy0W0R7gCZSVQu_QN2qD8uTeThan7Ad78GNteLdQN2TKPYJUVD3MrxeeT1YG_i4IYaa6zzENb9CKR1p3zcW9HmDNxA2">
    <div class="">
        <h4 class="title">
            جستجوی خودرو :
        </h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-md-push-10 col-sm-push-6 ">
                <div class="datepicker-wrap">
                    <label>از تاریخ </label>
                    <input name="CarFormDate" autocomplete="off" id="CarFromDate" type="text" class="input-text full-width hasDatepicker" placeholder="از تاریخ ">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-md-push-6 DestinationT">
                <div class="datepicker-wrap">
                    <label>تا تاریخ </label>
                    <input name="CarToDate" autocomplete="off" id="CarToDate" type="text" class="input-text full-width hasDatepicker" placeholder="تا تاریخ ">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-md-push-2 col-sm-push-6">
                <label> شهر</label>
                <div class="selector">
                    <select class="full-width" name="CarCity" id="CarCity">
                        <option value="1">کیش</option>
                    </select><span class="custom-select full-width">کیش</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-md-pull-2 col-sm-pull-6">
                <label>نوع خودرو</label>
                <div class="selector">
                    <select class="full-width" name="CarStyle" id="CarType">
                        <option value="1">سواری</option>
                        <option value="2">شاسی بلند</option>
                        <option value="21">کروک اسپورت</option>
                    </select><span class="custom-select full-width">سواری</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-md-pull-6 col-sm-push-6">
                <label class="transparent">جستجوی خودرو</label>
                <button class="full-width soap-icon-search" type="button" id="SearchCar">جستجوی خودرو</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

> How to fix this vulnerability:
>
> Check if this form requires CSRF
>   protection and implement CSRF countermeasures if necessary.

Is there problem in this case?

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

CSRF detection, by very nature, is hard to detect automatically and often requires some form of human verification to check whether the alert is a false positive or not.

There is a really detailed article by Acunetix below regarding CSRF tokens which I would recommend going over - https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/csrf-attacks/

If you need any further details, let me know.